# CDC-ACM driver returning garbage data

Tags: linux, usb, embedded

I'm trying to connect a u-Blox USB GPS device to an embedded (armel) Linux 2.6.32 system based on BusyBox. The device has a native CDC ACM USB interface. The system didn't come with cdc_acm, so I cross-compiled it, transferred & insmodded it, and it loaded successfully (confirmed by `dmesg`).

I plugged the device and it correctly got enumerated by the USB driver with address `001:003`, and assigned to the `cdc_acm` driver that created the `/dev/ttyACM0` file. However, opening the device with a serial terminal or even with the `cat` command, results in garbage being printed, whereas ASCII NMEA commands should be printed (this is confirmed to work on two other systems).

`stty` runs on the file without errors (however the reported data is obviously invalid/arbitrary, due to the device being a USB device and not a serial device). `lsusb -v -s 1:3` also reports the correct information for the device.

I don't know how to further debug the issue. What steps can I take to figure out the problem and solve it?

Comment: You might alternatively try the [generic serial](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usb-serial.txt) driver, search for `new_id`.

Comment: @meuh That should probably work, and if I'm not mistaken the driver is compiled into the kernel. I'll try.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem resided in the terminal settings.

By manually setting the right baudrate and raw mode, I started to get meaningful data from the device:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 57600
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw
```